# NVCC + Cereal, no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, header-files, nvcc

This question is doomed to repeat, until all the specific situations are exhausted. But this time it is really puzzling, because resolving "#includes" is usually not a problem.

---

**SITUATION**

IDE : Nsight

Cuda varsion : cuda-9.0

GPU computability : 3.7

*program structure*

```
main.cu
     |
     #include GPU_in_grig.cuh - defines class and C-structures with serialization functions
           |                   - #includes <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
           #include NN_def.cuh - defines C-structure, also with serialization functions
                               - #includes <cereal/archives/binary.hpp> <- ERROR
```

---

**ERROR**

```
14:14:19 ** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project cuda_managed_v0_2 **
    make all 
    Building file: ../source_code/main.cu
    Invoking: NVCC Compiler
    /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/nvcc -I"/home/mgaraj/cuda-workspace/cuda_managed_v0_2/source_code/cereal" -G -g -O0 -std=c++11 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37  -odir "source_code" -M -o "source_code/main.d" "../source_code/main.cu"
    In file included from ../source_code/GPU_in_grid.cuh:15:0,
                     from ../source_code/main.cu:9:
    ../source_code/NN_def.hpp:18:38: fatal error: cereal/archives/binary.hpp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make: * [source_code/main.o] Error 1
    source_code/subdir.mk:21: recipe for target 'source_code/main.o' failed

    14:14:19 Build Finished (took 172ms)
```

---

**Cereal**

For people not familiar with cereal library, this is header only library, just copy-pasted into my project into folder source_code, where all the code resides.

[image]

The above shows the file in question, causing the compilation error. Notice, the file is in source_code/cereal/archives, which is the  -cereal/archives/binary.hpp- as the error complains.

---

**My code**

```
#ifndef NN_DEF_H_
#define NN_DEF_H_

//==========================================================//
//                      INCLUDES                            //
//==========================================================//
// std::cout
#include <iostream>

// Cereal - serialization
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/portable_binary.hpp>


//==========================================================//
//                      PARAMETERS                          //
//==========================================================//
// OMITTED

//==========================================================//
//                      CLASS DEFINITION                    //
//==========================================================//
class NN{
public:
    bool check_limits(void);
    void print(void);

public:
    //==========================//
    //          CONTENT         //
    //==========================//
    float weight[NN_layer][NN_neuron][NN_weight];
    // ensure the size of NN_layout equals the NN_layer parameter
    int layout[NN_layer] = NN_layout;

    // debugging parameter
    int debug;

    //==========================//
    //      SERIALIZATION       //
    //==========================//
    // function required by cereal library
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar){
        ar( cereal::binary_data( weight , sizeof(float) * NN_layer * NN_neuron * NN_weight));
        ar( cereal::binary_data( layout , sizeof(float) * NN_layer) );
        ar( debug );
    }


};

//==========================================================//
//                      FUNCTION DEFINITION                 //
//==========================================================//

bool NN::check_limits(void){
// OMITTED
};

void NN::print(void){
// OMITTED
}

#endif /* NN_DEF_H_ */
```

---

**What I have done to cope with the error**

1. tested #include "..." and #include <...>

   - when using #include "..." option, the compiler then produces the same error, but with files inside the Cereal library, #include "cereal/cereal.hpp", in binary.hpp
2. using NVCCs option -I to include folder /source_code/cereal

   - no difference, still the same error
3. Renaming the NN_def.cuh, to NN_def.h, NN_def.hpp to force standard c++ compiler to handle the compilation

   - no difference

---

**QUESTION**

Why is the error so persistent ? Is the NVCC compiler causing problems ? Is it related to my code ?

Comment: The error is so "persistent" because at no point have you actually provided a valid search path to the compiler  which leads to cereal/archives

Comment: @talonmies well, how about the -I (capital "i") compiler option ? My 2nd point at the end of the post ...

Comment: As you note in your answer, they are not valid search paths

Answer (score 1):

The NVCC (or just simply compiler), when provided with -I option, "/source_code/cereal", doesnt understand the overlap with #include "cereal/archives/binary.hpp". The overlap is the "cereal/" directory included in both paths.

Simply letting the compiler know -I = "/source_code", solves the problem, since the #include "cereal/archives/binary.hpp" is then appended to the -I option, thus resulting in "source_code/cereal/archives/binary.hpp" path.